# Scala Cannot prove type equality

Tags: scala, types

I am defining an operable type:

```
trait Operable {
  def +[A](other: A)(implicit evidence: this.type =:= A): this.type
  def -[A](other: A)(implicit evidence: this.type =:= A): this.type
  def *[A](other: Float): this.type
}
/** Position descriptions */
trait Pos[T <: Operable] {
  def eval: T
}
def test[T <: Operable](x1: Pos[T], x2: Pos[T]): T = {
  x2.eval - x1.eval
}
```

And I get the following compile-time error:

```
 Cannot prove that _1.type =:= T.
```

Why can't the compiler prove the type equality, and how to overcome this problem? The T parameters from x1 and x2 should be the same. Why is it not the case?

Comment: I think the answer Régis gave you (use F-bounded polymorphism) is the way to go, but it's worth noting that the compiler will be happy with `<:<` rather than `=:=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.type` is the type of a specific instance. It is not compatible with any other instance, even if instances of the exact same type.
So basically in this definition:

```
def -[A](other: A)(implicit evidence: this.type =:= A): this.type
```

your evidence tries to prove that `other` is the exact same instance as `this`, which is probably not what you has in mind.

I think you'll want to rework your design. You might try to use F-bounded polymorphism instead:

```
trait Operable[Self <: Operable[Self]] {
  def +(other: Self): Self
  def -(other: Self): Self
  def *(other: Float): Self
}
/** Position descriptions */
trait Pos[T <: Operable[T]] {
  def eval: T
}
def test[T <: Operable[T]](x1: Pos[T], x2: Pos[T]): T = {
  x2.eval - x1.eval
}
```

Comment: Do you have a good link describing what a F-Bounded polymorphism is?

Comment: I can suggest twitter's scala school: http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded